# What will happen if each atom contains 2% less protons than electron?

Tags: forces, atoms

While reading the structure of atom i thought what will happen if all the atoms contain 2% less protons than electrons.

I thought every body in the  universe will become charged,everything will attract every other thing with  strong electromagnetic force.

By assuming above fact I tried to find the force acting  between television (say 10kg) and mobile phone (say 100g) kept at a distance of 1 metre, but I found that solution is far from scope of my knowledge.

What are the consequences of the above fact?

Comment: Like charges _repel_, so everything would repel everything else. How does the 2% apply to atoms with less than 50 electrons? And how are the atoms supposed to hang onto those extra electrons?

Comment: Such electrically unbalanced atoms exist all over in this universe. They are named ions. For example $Na^+$ is what leads to the building of the salt.

Comment: Individual atoms can have that charges about 2% no problem.   The problem comes i when you try to get every atom (say, in your phone) with that charge.  Atoms with a slight positive charge want to bond with atoms with a negative charge.    Your phone or any other physical object big enough to see would come apart or give off electric sparks long before holding a charge anywhere close to that.   Are you asking for a numerical answer or to confirm an answer of our own?

Comment: @userltk i was supposing to get the amount of force by which two heavy enough bodies will repel each other

Comment: The force would depend on how big a ratio of electrons can be added or removed, but most compounds aren't good at holding a significant charge because electrons are good at moving.   Batteries are OK at holding a charge, but designed to move electrons when a path is provided, so there's may be better materials.   A TV or cellphone are designed to either charges run through their circuitry, or to insulate around the circuitry, so nether has the material to hold charge well.    I don't know enough about the properties of materials to say how strong a charge a specific material can hold.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it deals with unphysical situations.

Comment: @garyp I can't imagine why would it be unphysical, while even [extremal charged black holes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reissner–Nordström_metric) are perfectly physical.

Comment: why continuous downvotes??

Comment: My reason for down-voting is first that you haven't shown any effort to make the calculation yourself. If this has been asked by your teacher, you will already have the knowledge to make a calculation - it will not be "beyond your knowledge". Second that your reasoning is way off : like charges repel, not attract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This situation would not be impossible, but it would change chemistry, the structure of materials, and life - completely.

Atoms of elements #51, #102, #153, etc would be neutral and could form bulk metallic or covalent structures, but atoms of all other elements would carry a fractional charge of between +1 and -1, and would only exist as ionic compounds. De-localised electron bonding might be more prevalent, resulting in many more interesting large molecular structures. Possible compounds and their chemistry would be very different from those we are familiar with.

Whether TV and mobile technologies could be built from such compounds is not clear to me. What is clear is that bulk items would **not** necessarily have large net charges equal to 2% of the protons in them. So I think the premise of the problem is flawed.

**However**, since this is only an exercise I shall suspend belief and assume that objects carrying such large charges could be made without them disintegrating due to the mutual repulsion of their constituent charged atoms.

---

**Step 1. Estimate the number of protons in 1 kg of matter**

The number of protons per atom depends on the element, and there are various elements found in TVs and mobile phones. So take carbon (12 protons) to be a typical atom. (You could use silicon or aluminium instead - any abundant element will do. We are only looking for an order-of-magnitude calculation.) Look up the mass of a carbon atom, then calculate the number of atoms thence protons in 1 kg of carbon.

**Step 2. Calculate the net charges on a 10 kg TV and 0.1 kg mobile phone**

Look up the charge on the proton. The net charge per kg of matter is 2% of the charge on the total number of protons in that 1 kg. Use that result to work out the charges on the TV an mobile phone.

**Step 3. Use the Coulomb Law to Calculate the Force between the TV and mobile phone**

Answer (score 1):

The math is pretty straight forward.

An individual electron has a charge of $1.6 \cdot 10^{-19}$ coulombs.  ($1.6021766$, but I'm rounding to $1.6$).

Lets take the 2nd simplest atom, a helium atom, 2 protons, 2 neutrons, 2 electrons. (The reason I didn't choose hydrogen is that it mostly has no neutrons, all the other atoms do). 1 mole of helium is $2.602 \cdot 10^{26}$ atoms (rounding to 2.6), so $5.2\cdot 10^{26}$ protons, neutrons, electrons and mass of about 4 grams.

Take away 2% of the electrons, the charge of the object is the missing 2%, or $-1.04 \cdot 10^{25}$. So multiply the charge by the electron to Coulomb ratio and we get: $1.6\cdot 10^{-19} \cdot -1.04 \cdot 10^{25} = -1.664 \cdot 10^6$ charge in Coulombs.

Now lets take 2 of these little balls of helium (pretend they're contained somehow) and separate them by 10 meters, using the formulas [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170911021214/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/66744.html):

$F = \frac{K \cdot q \cdot q'}{d^2}$, where $K = 9\cdot 10^9 \frac{N \cdot m^2}{C^2}$

$9\cdot 10^9 \cdot \frac{(-1.664 \cdot 10^6)^2}{10^2}$, and you get $2.49 \cdot 10^{20}$, or 249 billion billion newtons of repulsive force between the 2 small containers of charged helium.

For any object, like your phone or a TV, the Proton/Neutron Ratio isn't too far off from 1 to 1 but adjust for that, adjust for the 2 masses, and there's your answer. The above answer is with two 4 gram objects. If your calculation showed that the force was enormous, then you may have done the calculation correctly.

2%, however, is a grossly unrealistic number of electrons to remove from any physical object. More realistic numbers are about a million billion times lower. (I looked, but couldn't find any specifics on highest charges a particular object is likely to hold). 2 charged objects are unlikely to cause any significant force between them, like 2 of the same poles of 2 magnets, unless they are pushed very close together.

Comment: balls are attracting or repelling each other???(both have negetive charge)

Comment: Electrons have a negative charge in common connotation but a positive charge in coulombs, which is wrong, but that's how it's always been.  That's why there are no negative numbers in my calculation.   But the force is repulsion, I should have said that so I'll edit.

Comment: I also just noticed, you said 2% less protons, I calculated 2% less electrons, which should give it a negative coulomb charge (but the square of a negative doesn't change the end result).   Adjusted accordingly.

Comment: yes i didn't mentioned it because i just wanted the way how to approach for this problem

Comment: I fixed your latex, now, but it was big work. Latex is a quite simple markup, I think you could easily learn it.